# iOS provisioning, team ID confusion

Tags: ios, provisioning

I am a member of 3 registered iOS Development teams:

- My individual iOS Developer account.
- My business iOS Developer account team.
- My client's iOS Developer account team.

I would now like to use the iOS Provisioning Portal to create a new App ID.

As part of the App ID form for creating a new App ID, I need to select a Team ID.  I've done this many times before, but I think something may have changed, because today, when selecting the Team ID, I'm offered the choice of 3 10-character identifiers of the form (these are not the actual values),

- Use Team ID
- YH78GU29T
- GH6R89TRW
- JK32DE724

Unfortunately, it isn't clear how each of these correspond to the teams I'm a member of...

If I go to Xcode Organiser to try and find references to these Team IDs to get some context, I see that those views [more helpfully] use the team's full names ...but without visibility on the corresponding Team IDs.

I've looked under the Key Chain, and there are no clues there either.

How do I find out which of the teams I a member of these IDs correspond to?

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you're looking but can you figure it out based on the projects per app id?

Comment: Unfortunately not, AFAIK, you can't isolate the Team ID that an existing App ID was created from.

Comment: What I mean is if you have created app id's for a specific project you can go into iOS Provisioning Portal and look at the description. The team id will appear as the first of the id. example **XYZ1234ZXY .com.server.appname**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, go to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action click `your account` then on the left click `organization profile` and it will show you the `Company/Organization ID`

Comment: I also realised that you don't actually need to select an ID, and the 'Use Team ID' choice is a valid option.  If you use this, it will select your default Team ID (presumably the team you chose at log on).  With this (or any other) option selected, it doesn't look like the Submit button is enabled, but it is.

Comment: Yea, I always just use team id, but I use different emails for all my accounts so I wasn't sure if you specified which team you log in as

Comment: @mkral Maybe dev.apple has changed, but mine only says professional profile. I don't see my team here.

Answer (score 6):

Find out your certificates in Keychain Access, right click on the Certificate and select Get info. Then locate scroller down to Details section and Expand it if needed. There you can find User ID or Team ID.

Hope it helps!